# AVAudioPlayer plays music in iPod touch 2G and 3G

Tags: ios, avaudioplayer, ipod-touch

I'm trying to play an audio file on iPhone and iPod touch with **AVAudioPlayer**. The code works fine in **iPhone** and **iPod touch 4G**, I can hear the music. But when I test it on **iPod touch 2G**, **iPod touch 3G**, I can't hear anything.

Below is the code I use to play audio file:

```
NSString *zeroAudioPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"TimerBell"
                                                          ofType:@"aif"];
NSURL *file = [[NSURL alloc] initFileURLWithPath:zeroAudioPath];
AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file
                                                                    error:nil];
[file release];

self.zeroAudioPlayer = audioPlayer;
zeroAudioPlayer.delegate = self;
[audioPlayer release];
[zeroAudioPlayer prepareToPlay];
[zeroAudioPlayer play];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that changing from `kAudioSessionCategory_PlayAndRecord` to `kAudioSessionCategory_AmbientSound` corrected this issue.  I suspect this has something to do with a hardware difference on the iPod touch related to recording.

Answer (score 1):

You should use audiosession like this before you play:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&error];
```